# emacsclient : Can't open display

Tags: ubuntu, emacs

I'm trying to open a new emacs frame by connecting to an existing emacs daemon with the below command, but it fails to open the display.

This is the command:

emacsclient -c

The output is:

Waiting for Emacs...
*ERROR*: Display :1 can't be opened

The $DISPLAY is :0

No idea why the error message indicates display :1

I even tried emacsclient -c -d :0 with the same result.

Other X programs start without problems, e.g. xclock, xeyes, etc.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you starting your Emacs daemon? Did you perhaps start `emacs` with `DISPLAY=:1`?

Comment: not really. $ps -C emacs wwe | grep -o "DISPLAY.*"
DISPLAY=:0 XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=LXDE TEXTDOMAINDIR=/usr/share/locale/ ... Anyway, I started using emacsclient -t -a

Comment: make sure you don't run `emacs --daemon` or `emacsclient -c` under root user - I got the same error, which got resolved when i rerun the commands under non-root user

Answer (score 1):

It worked after restarting emacs daemon, but still not sure why didn't work the first time...

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out the answer to this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15495/emacs-cant-open-display):

It could be due to the fact that emacsclient needs the same $XAUTHORITY as the emacsserver process, but if you started the emacs server process on your desktop or in another session, it may not have put the XAUTHORITY credientals where emacsclient is looking for it.